# The concentration $c(t)$ of a toxin added to water pipes is given by $c(t)=\dfrac{0.2t}{(t+2)^2}$

Tags: calculus

The concentration $c(t)$ of a toxin added to water pipes is given by $c(t)=\dfrac{0.2t}{(t+2)^2}$ where $t$ is the number of hours after the toxin enters the water. Determine the maximum and minimum concentration between the first half hour and the fifth hour after the toxin enters the water pipes.

Comment: You need to maimize/minimize the given function in the omterval $0.5\le t \le 5$. Standard calculation, set the derivative equal to $0$, The candidates are (i) the place(s) in the interval where the derivative is $0$ and (ii) $0.5$ and $5$.

Answer (score 0):

To find the maximum, we can take the derivative of $c(t)$ and set it to $0$. That is,
$$\frac{dc}{dt} = \frac{0.4-0.2t}{(t+2)^3} = 0$$
and obtain the critical $t$-value of $t=2$. Plugging that in to $c(t)$, we get
$$c(2)=\frac{0.2t}{(t+2)^2} \Bigg\vert_{t=2}=\frac{0.2(2)}{((2)+2)^2}=\frac{1}{40}$$
So the maximum concentration of toxin is $\frac{1}{40}$ which occurs at $t=2$ hours.

To find the minimum, all I can think up is to graph the function between the interval $0.5 \le t \le 5$. The function on that interval kind of looks like a hill. By inspection, the lowest value occurs at the end of the interval (at $t=5$). At $t=5$, $c(t) = \frac{1}{49}$.

Comment: Not sure about analytically finding the minimum though.